# Calculating power absorbed by time varying unit step souce in pspice

Tags: power, pulse, pspice

I am new to Pspice and I am encountering a problem. I want to find the power absorbed at  specific given time lets say t = 0.1s using pspice. I have the following circuit with a time varying source. I think I have to use a IPULSE source but I am still unsure of the parameters to use and how to find power directly. The circuit is given below[image]

Comment: What is u(t)? Can you explain?

Comment: @Andyaka it is a unit step function. (It has a value of 0 from t<0 and 1 for t>0)